# How to determine size of collection view when using two different type of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How to determine size collection view when I use two different type of cell and the size of one of these cells is always one but other one's size are depend on array and because of that its size is dynamic.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell
            cell.bioLabelText.text = bio
            return cell
        }else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CountryCollectionViewCell

            cell.countryLabel.text = city
            cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "lake.jpg")
            cell.makeRounded()
            return cell
        }
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return uniqueCountryArray.count

    }
```

my ProfileCell number should be one and the number of other cell should be uniqueCountryArray.count. However when I write "return uniqueCountryArray.count + 1" , it gives me error. When I write "return uniqueCountryArray.count" , I missed one array element.

How can I take all of array elements dynamically ? And id array size is 0, I should still show I cell comes from profile Cell.

Comment: what kind of error? Could you please give the description of the error?

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: How you get the `city` in `CountryCollectionViewCell `? Is it a static variable?

Comment: nope it comes from array like "city = uniqueCountryArray[indexPath.row]"

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `city = uniqueCountryArray[indexPath.row]` to `city = uniqueCountryArray[indexPath.row-1]` like below

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileCollectionViewCell
        cell.bioLabelText.text = bio
        return cell
    }
    else {

        let city = uniqueCountryArray[indexPath.row-1]

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CountryCollectionViewCell
        cell.countryLabel.text = city
        cell.imgView.image = UIImage(named: "lake.jpg")
        cell.makeRounded()
        return cell
    }
}
```

And `numberOfItemsInSection` will be `uniqueCountryArray.count+1`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return uniqueCountryArray.count+1
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. Can you please explain why should I take "uniqueCountryArray[indexPath.row-1]" index ?

Comment: Because first cell of TableView is `ProfileCollectionViewCell `. So your first `CountryCollectionViewCell` is actually the 2nd cell of TableView. And you want to show the first element of the `uniqueCountryArray` in that cell.

Comment: I understand perfectly. Thank you.